# Can you take vitamins on a fast day?

Tags: halacha, fast-days, health-safety-shmira, medicine

Can you take vitamins on a fast day?

Comment: Somewhere Rav Moshe Feinstein says that vitamins need a hashgacha because they provide 'sustenance.' That could be relevant here...

Comment: Can you take vitamins on a fast day?

Answer (score 3):

A partial answer: I have heard from my rabbi, but of course contact your own for an halachic ruling, that prenatal vitamins (prescription or over-the-counter) which one's doctor says to take have the same rule as any other medicine prescribed by a doctor.

Comment: Many women taking prenatals do not observe minor fasts, and likely would be eating Shi'urim anyway for major fasts.

Comment: R'Seth: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/4689

Comment: @msh Very thorough. Why not post that link as an answer to this question?  As for pregnant women, I can only tell you that 1, I assume most, but not all, women taking prenatal vitamins are pregnant, and 2, I was witness and party to a pregnant woman's psak from a respected Rav to eat Shi'urim and that anything that fit in the Shi'ur, liquid or solid, food, medicine, or antacid, was fair game.

Comment: I didn't realize you were the author of the partial answer.

Comment: And the anecdote was on Y"K following Kol Nidrei.

Comment: @SethJ you acknowledge not everyone taking prenatal vitamins is pregnant.  I'd note that some women take them while trying to become pregnant.

Answer (score 2):

Swallowing a regular pill is not considered eating food, and is permitted on a fast day and does not require a bracha. However, chewable bills (that have flavor) are different, and probably cannot  be taken on a fast.

Comment: +1, with the caveat that one is not allowed to drink water to swallow the vitamin pill on a fast day.  (Again, unless this person is ill, and a doctor has mandated that this person must take a vitamin pill on this day - but if one is that ill, perhaps one ought not fast at all).

Answer (score 1):

I would think not, unless they were prescribed by a doctor. Vitamins are not medicine and are taken voluntarily and therefore would not be considered as a danger if you miss taking them one day.

Comment: source source source